# Passing a value into a struct with generic type

Tags: generics, struct, swiftui

I have written a struct with a generic type like this:

```
struct AlphabetGrid<Letter: View>: View {
    var letters: [[Letter]]
    var spacing: CGFloat = 8
    ...
```

But I'd like to pass in the value of `spacing` when I instantiate the struct, so I can use it in different situations. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You should be able to pass `spacing` as a parameter just like a struct with non-Generic constraints. Is there something you tried that didn't work as you expected?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified default value for spacing, but you can use this parameter in constructor explicitly to provide new one, like

```
AlphabetGrid(letters: [[Text("Demo1"), Text("Demo2")]], spacing: 12)
```